# c# Refresh a child form owned by a parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, button, permissions

I have a parentForm MainForm with a button Start. Start calls a Click event StartForm_Click which opens a childForm, that has is owned by it's parent MainForm and is modeless, Start. On the Start form I have a button Permissions which opens a modeless form that is owned by it's parentForm Start. The form Permissions has a bunch of dynamically created checkboxes. When I click a button Modify button on Permissions I would like for Permissions to update the checkboxes that are viewable.

I know when I click the Modify button the permissions.txt file is being updated appropriately. The UI dialog is not updating to reflect the correct (modified) number of users approved under that permissions category. How can I force the child of a child owned by it's parent to update the UI when I click the button Modify on the form Permissions.

Call from MainForm to open childForm Start

```
    private void StartForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start f1 = new Start();
        f1.Owner = this;
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Call from Start to make childForm Permissions to open

```
    private void bPermissions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Permissions af3 = new Permissions();
        af3.Owner = this;
        af3.Show();
        WidgetLogic.getPermText(af3);
        WidgetLogic.getDetailerPermText(af3);
        WidgetLogic.getAdminPermText(af3);

    }
```

The various WidgetLogic calls update the permissions.txt files on the server. Next is where I think my problem is

```
    private void bModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WidgetLogic.writePerm();

    }
```

WidgetLogic here is writing the file. I've tried simple this.Refresh(); and I can't seem to call to Start.bPermission_Click();. Unfortunately because Start owns Permissions, required as when Start closes all children form must immediately Dispose(); for fear the user will surely muck something up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I would sincerely appreciate it. Thank You Very Much in advance. :-D

Comment: Can you access the check boxes in `Permissions` form via an index eg *chkPerm[i]*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[c# Gather checkbox.Click events for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487297/c-sharp-gather-checkbox-click-events-for-later-use)

Your logic in `checkChangedPerm()` is not correct. You need to check if the *checkbox* is checked or un-checked:

```
public static void checkChangedPerm(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox c = sender as CheckBox;

    if (c.Name != null && c.Name != "")
    {
        StreamReader reader;
        int count = c.Name.Count();
        string trimmed = c.Name.ToString();
        string outPut = trimmed.Remove(count - 4);            

        using (reader = new StreamReader(dataFolder + PermFile))
        {
            //Here you check the state of checkbox
            if(c.Checked == false) //add the name in permLine_
            {
                trimmed = reader.ReadToEnd(); //re-use the trimmed string. Don't need a new one

                if (!trimmed.Contains(outPut))
                {
                    trimmed +=  "\r\n" + outPut;
                    permLine_ = trimmed;
                }
            }
            else //remove name from permLine_
            {
                permLine_ = "";
                while ((trimmed = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (trimmed != outPut)
                    {
                        permLine_ += trimmed + "\r\n";
                    }                        
                }
                if (permLine_ != "")
                {
                    permLine_ = permLine_.Remove(permLine_.Length - 2); //trim the last \r\n
                }
            }

            //Now permLine_ contains the correct string
        }
    }                
}
```

In `writePerm()`:

```
StreamWriter writer;

if(permLine_ == "" || permLine_ == null){return;}

foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
{
    if (C.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox))
    {
        if (!permLine_.Contains(C.Name))
        {
            C.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

using (writer = new StreamWriter(dataFolder + PermFile))
{
    writer.Write(permLine_);
}
```

Finally, in `getPermText()` you need to add this line of code after `line = reader.ReadToEnd();`

```
//Initialize permLine_ string with the contains of the file.
permLine_ = line;
```

and check if userCount is zero:

```
...
...
userCount = parts.Length;

if(userCount == 0){return;}

CheckBox[] chkPerm = new CheckBox[userCount];
...
...
```

**EDIT**

It is a little embarrassing but the solution is way more simple. What i mean is, you need to update the file whenever you press the button `bModify`. So there is no need for the `checkChangedPerm()` function nor to change the `permLine_` string every time a `checkbox` is clicked. Just rewrite the `bModify_Click()`:

```
private void bModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter writer;
    string trimmed = "", outPut = "";
    int count;

    foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
    {
        if (C.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            if ( ((CheckBox)C).Checked == true ) { C.Visible = false; }
            else
            {
                count = C.Name.Count();
                trimmed = C.Name.ToString();
                outPut += trimmed.Remove(count - 4) + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if (outPut != "")
    {
        outPut = outPut.Remove(outPut.Length - 2); //trim the last \r\n
    }

    using (writer = new StreamWriter(dataFolder + PermFile))
    {
         writer.WriteLine(outPut);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

You can have the `writePerm()` function in `WidgetLogic Class` like this:

```
public static void writePerm(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
{
    StreamWriter writer;
    string trimmed = "", outPut = "";
    int count;

    foreach (Control C in targetForm.Controls)
    {
        if (C.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            if ( ((CheckBox)C).Checked == true ) { C.Visible = false; }
            else
            {
                count = C.Name.Count();
                trimmed = C.Name.ToString();
                outPut += trimmed.Remove(count - 4) + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if (outPut != "")
    {
        outPut = outPut.Remove(outPut.Length - 2); //trim the last \r\n
    }

    using (writer = new StreamWriter(dataFolder + PermFile))
    {
         writer.WriteLine(outPut);
    }
}
```

and call it normally:

```
private void bModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WidgetLogic.writePerm(this);
}
```

Comment: The only error that I'm not able to clear is the foreach(Control C in this.Controls). the keyword this is giving me a not valid error in any static condition. I tried changing the Access Modifiers and including C as a part of/similar to that called in checkChangedPerm(). I was unable to clear the error. Frankly I think the whole line foreach (Control C in this.Controls) could be causing me trouble. I'll have to think on this in the morning. My day is done. Thank you very much again. You have greatly speed up my process. HAGD!! :-D I'll keep you in the loop.

Comment: Oh, I don't think I'll ever have to worry about a userCount of zero. If I let them try it, they break it and I have to fix it. Which is exactly what I want. :-D

Comment: Sorry I missed this. I've been beating my head against the wall for an hour. I'm trying to keep the writePerm() in the WidgetLogic. Your edit is saying the solution is to keep the code in bModify_Click(). At the moment I can't see why I would ((EDIT: REMOVE not)) want to have the modify button in WidgetLogic.cs. Really it will never be used anywhere else and that should solve it. Processing....

Comment: Processing.... They pulled me back to my regular job. I'll definitely let you know how it goes. Thanks Again!! :-D

Comment: I've figured out that this is looking through all of the checkboxes (actually all of the controls. Labels, buttons, etc.), not just those that are qualified by "*Perm" or "*Admin". I think, not sure yet, that I want to be able to call these separately. I've figured out that what I need to do is check the C.Name control property and only test for those items containing a suffix "Perm" or "Admin". Are you aware of a C# operator that checks a string to see if it 'contains' "Perm" or "Admin". I'm working on that portion of it now. I really do appreciate your help. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @FrankPytel C.Name.Contains ("Perm")

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Please see my post. Thank You for all of your direction. Brilliant!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Brilliant. Many thanks to all over the many threads. Especially thank you to @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε

Ultimately this person put many usable answers directly in front of me. I found the last answer to be more to my liking, primarily in hopes of using code further in the project. First called through a button on the main form Permissions is WidgetLogic.writePerm(this); so the form would be iterated through for the appropriate checkboxes to modify. At that time the checkboxes are removed from the form and unavailable to the user.

```
    public static void writePerm(System.Windows.Forms.Form targetForm)
    {
        StreamWriter writer;
        string trimmed = "", outPut = "";
        int count;

        foreach (Control C in targetForm.Controls)
        {
            if (C.Name.Contains("Perm"))
            {

                if (C.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)C).Checked == true)
                    {
                        C.Visible = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        count = C.Name.Count();
                        trimmed = C.Name.ToString();
                        outPut += trimmed.Remove(count - 4) + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (outPut != "")
        {
            outPut = outPut.Remove(outPut.Length - 2); //trim the last \r\n

        }

        using (writer = new StreamWriter(dataFolder + PermFile))
        {

            writer.Write(outPut);
        }
    }
```

As originally written this checked all Control items (including Labels, Buttons, etc.) if they were checkboxes and proceeded accordingly.

by writing another simple if()

```
if (C.Name.Contains("Perm"))
```

that would check only those checkboxes that have the string "Perm" appended to the checkbox.Name. "Perm" was added at runtime to the checkbox.Name with the UserID as the checkbox.Name property.

I also had to change from writer.WriteLine(output) to writer.Write(output). This removed a final \r\n that was being automatically appended to the file which in turn created valueless and Nameless checkboxes.

Works like a charm. Thank You again @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε  Brilliant. I really appreciate your patience and assistance with this. Pointed me in the right direction for sure. Required me to really dig to understand everything that was going on.

Have an Awesome Day!! :-D